How to make a pagination which has move(prev, next) 10pages at once
Background

I am using Elementor Pro, which provides a loop widget that allows us to loop through WP_Query results.
The loop widget comes with a built-in pagination feature.

Problem

In addition to the default pagination functionality, I would like to add "10-page movement" icons to navigate through the pages more efficiently.

Below is the relevant code from Elementor:
protected function render_loop_footer() {
    // ...

    $links = [];

    if ( $has_numbers ) {
        $paginate_args = [
            'type' => 'array',
            'current' => $this->parent->get_current_page(),
            'total' => $page_limit,
            'prev_next' => false,
            'show_all' => 'yes' !== $parent_settings['pagination_numbers_shorten'],
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="elementor-screen-only">' . esc_html__( 'Page', 'elementor-pro' ) . '</span>',
        ];

        // ...

        $links = paginate_links( $paginate_args );
    }

    if ( $has_prev_next ) {
        $prev_next = $this->parent->get_posts_nav_link( $page_limit );
        array_unshift( $links, $prev_next['prev'] );
        $links[] = $prev_next['next'];
    }

    // ...
}

The main part of the code that generates the pagination links is $links = paginate_links( $paginate_args );.
My goal is to modify the pagination to include "10-page movement" buttons, like this:
<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > >>
By clicking the >> button, users should be able to navigate to the next 10 pages at once.
How can I achieve this functionality with the paginate_links( $paginate_args ); function  ?
